# How do I create a Smooth Material for my Model?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I'm trying to render something like this :

[image: smooth surface]

It has a really smooth and nice surface. But I still can't figure out the shading or lighting compositions. I'm using Cycles mainly.

Comment: Please do not offer money for help. Blender Stack Exchange is **_not_** a marketplace of some sorts.

Comment: Why not? If someone gives answers gladly, I will be very happy. If they also give help professionally, I'm also happy to "support" them in exchange for some "coffee" or "beer". I ask this for a work-related issue, not just for a hobby. @metaphor_set

Comment: Because Blender Stack Exchange is not a market place of some sorts. It's also not social media or any type of forum. It's a q&a site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use smooth shading on the geometry of the object
2. Use a subsurface modifier to make sure there are no remaining sharp edges
3. Use a high roughness value, like 0.8 or higher
4. Use subsurface scattering to give it a plastic look, as if some light is passing through thinner sections, but this is optional
5. Use a large light source/lamp that won't cast sharp shadows.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try that.

Comment: If you're struggling with lighting, you could try the three-point lighting system. If thats relevent to your question